# Why will Swift not accept this NSCalendar method call?

Tags: swift, nsdate

```
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.MonthCalendarUnit, fromDate: dateCreated, toDate: NSDate(), options: 0)
```

I'm trying to find the difference between two NSDates in months, but this function will *not* cooperate. It keeps complaining about "extra argument 'toDate' in call", but it's definitely supposed to be there.

Comment: By the way, `.MonthCalendarUnit` is deprecated in favor of `.CalendarUnitMonth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't accept `0` as a value for `options`, like Objective-C. Use `nil` instead:

```
let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.MonthCalendarUnit, fromDate: dateCreated, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)
```

Then all you have to do is get the number of months by doing `dateComponents.month`.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension NSDate {
    func monthsFrom(date:NSDate) -> Int{
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitMonth, fromDate: date, toDate: self, options: nil).month
    }
}

let dateX = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2014, month: 11, day: 28, hour: 5, minute: 9, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
let dateY = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 22, minute: 51, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!

let months = dateY.monthsFrom(dateX)  // 1
```